# Windows 7 start two applications side by side

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 machine that runs an industrial application. It has no user input, but a screen that displays the applications state.

Two different programs (closed source, unmodifiable) need to run side by side (split screen) on the same monitor. Is there a inbuilt way in Windows to start a program on a specific side of the screen? If not is there a tool to achieve this? In Linux I would use Devil’s Pie for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a tool for this, but I never found out as I use pywinauto for all of those types of problems, even though pywin32 actually is enough for moving and resizing windows that can be moved and resized by users.

http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.html